# I want to show react js moment timer text after finishing the time, days, hours, minutes and seconds in my app

Tags: html, css, reactjs, windows, momentjs

Guys help me i Want to show text , ' Sale is CLosed ' When days hours, minutes and seconds approaches to zero
i mean after expiration of given time , want to show some ui ,
also i want to show Ui Message ' Sale Not Started ' when sale will start in given timme .

thats what i need. Screenshot of UI is Attached. Please Check.[Project Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVVir.jpg)

```
const ReCaptach = () => {
  const difference = +new moment('2023-12-16 23:30').utc() - +new Date();
  const difference1 = +new moment('2023-12-16 05:30').utc() - +new Date();
  const [days, setDays] = useState(0);
  const [hours, setHours] = useState(0);
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(0);
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
  const [days1, setDays1] = useState(0);
  const [hours1, setHours1] = useState(0);
  const [minutes1, setMinutes1] = useState(0);
  const [seconds1, setSeconds1] = useState(0);
  const [text, setText] = useState(0);
  const [verfied, setVerifed] = useState(false);




  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      if (difference > 0) {
        setDays(Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
        setHours(Math.floor((difference / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24));
        setMinutes(Math.floor((difference / 1000 / 60) % 60));
        setSeconds(Math.floor((difference / 1000) % 60));
        setText('Minting Closed');

      }
      if (difference1 > 0) {
        setDays1(Math.floor(difference1 / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
        setHours1(Math.floor((difference1 / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24));
        setMinutes1(Math.floor((difference1 / 1000 / 60) % 60));
        setSeconds1(Math.floor((difference1 / 1000) % 60));
      }
      if (days === hours === minutes === seconds === 0) {
        setText('Minting Closed');
      }
    }, 1000);



    return () => {
      clearTimeout(id);

    };
  });



css and html

<div
        style={{
          border: '1px solid white',
          borderRadius: '5px',
          padding: '20px',
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
          }}
        >
          <h1 style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>WL MINT</h1>
          <div
            style={{
              display: 'flex',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}
          >
            Ending in:{' '}
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', marginLeft: '10px' }}>
              <div
                style={{
                  background: 'blue',
                  marginLeft: '7px',
                  padding: '5px',
                  borderRadius: '3px',
                }}
              >

                {days < 10 ? `0${days}` : days}
              </div>
              <div
                style={{
                  background: 'blue',
                  marginLeft: '7px',
                  padding: '5px',
                  borderRadius: '3px',
                }}
              >
                {hours < 10 ? `0${hours}` : hours}
              </div>
              <div
                style={{
                  background: 'blue',
                  marginLeft: '7px',
                  padding: '5px',
                  borderRadius: '3px',
                }}
              >
                {minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes}
              </div>
              <div
                style={{
                  background: 'blue',
                  marginLeft: '7px',
                  padding: '5px',
                  borderRadius: '3px',
                }}
              >
                {seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds}
                {text}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I tried Cleartimeout. but not worked in my way.
Operating system winodws.
Package Yarn
Language React Js

Answer (score 0):

Here's the modified version of your code,Try this :

```
const ReCaptach = () => {
  const saleEnd = moment('2023-12-16 23:30').utc();
  const saleStart = moment('2023-12-16 05:30').utc();

  const [days, setDays] = useState(0);
  const [hours, setHours] = useState(0);
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(0);
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const currentTime = moment().utc();

      if (currentTime.isBefore(saleStart)) {
        const diffStart = moment.duration(saleStart.diff(currentTime));
        setDays(diffStart.days());
        setHours(diffStart.hours());
        setMinutes(diffStart.minutes());
        setSeconds(diffStart.seconds());
        setText('Sale Not Started');
      } else if (currentTime.isBetween(saleStart, saleEnd)) {
        const diffEnd = moment.duration(saleEnd.diff(currentTime));
        setDays(diffEnd.days());
        setHours(diffEnd.hours());
        setMinutes(diffEnd.minutes());
        setSeconds(diffEnd.seconds());
        setText('Sale Closing Soon');
      } else {
        setText('Sale is Closed');
        clearInterval(interval); // Stop the interval when the sale is closed
      }
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval); // Cleanup the interval on component unmount
  }, [saleStart, saleEnd]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>WL MINT</h1>
      <div>
        <p>
          {text}
        </p>
        <p>
          {days < 10 ? `0${days}` : days} : {hours < 10 ? `0${hours}` : hours} :{' '}
          {minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes} : {seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```